# When to use "on" vs. "in"

Tags: word-choice, sentence-construction

Not sure which one is correct:

> On our scenario ..

Or,

> In our scenario ..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use "on our scenario" when someone or something is going to do something to or about the scenario.

*Many people will have some input on our scenario.*

Or, Yoda-like: *On our scenario, many people will comment.*

Use "in our scenario" when talking about things that can be considered as a component of, aspect of, or consequence of the scenario.

*In our scenario, people will be permitted to log on anonymously.*

All together now.

*In our scenario, people may log on anonymously and comment on our new scenario.*